# batch to copy files not working properly

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one batch script which will first delete any files created from previous run and then call 18 separate batch scripts in a subfolder "script".

Each of the 18 scripts runs an SQL and places the output as csv in the subfolder "script", then copies the result to another subfolder "Result", deletes the original output.

when i exceute the 18 batch files manually, they work as required. But when i use the main calling script, the files are copied into main folder instead of subfolder "Result"

here is a shortened version of the two

Main Script

```
del J:\BatchSQL\Result\ala.csv

start J:\BatchSQL\script\ALA.bat

exit
```

Sub script

```
Run SQLPlus call here

copy J:\BatchSQL\script\ALA.csv J:\BatchSQL\Result\ALA.csv

del J:\BatchSQL\script\ALA.csv

exit
```

Comment: Are they the actual full paths/file names that you are using? bear in mind that if the path has spaces it will need to be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, for lack of full information, that `main` executes `sub` and the destination for the created files is the current directory as far as the `main` script is concerned whereas when you execute the `sub` manually (probably from `J:\batchsql\script`) then *that* is where the files are created.

So - `main` is run from the `main` directory (wherever that is - you don't say) and hence SQLplus deposits the reports there. The copy and del in `sub` are ineffective since the subject file does not exist.

If you run `sub` manually with current directory `J:\BatchSQL\script`, that's where SQLplus puts its output and the `copy/del` can find the output file.

Test:

add

```
echo %cd%
pause
```

at the start of `sub` and see whether the directory reported is familiar.